# What's the difference between amusing and diverting?

Tags: differences

I was watching [Flushed Away (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0424095/) . In one scene (00:20:46) The Toad says

> I know you'll find it diverting.

and a minute later (00:21:57) Roddy says :

> Yes. I'd love to see more of your collection. It's very amusing, but
> l...

which makes the Toad angry. I looked it up in Longman dictionary and it says diverting means:

> entertaining and amusing

It looks like they have the same meaning. So, here is my question: what's the difference between "Amusing" and "Diverting"?

Comment: When something is *diverting* it has sufficient interest to capture your attention for a while and take your mind off other things; it may delight and instruct; when something is *amusing*, you laugh at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Diverting* has a broader application than *amusing*: semantically speaking, *amusing* is a subset of *diverting* (and *diverting* has essentially the same meaning as *entertaining*).

However, they do not all occupy the same register: *diverting* is more highfaluting than both *amusing* and *entertaining.*

Comment: I've just been amusing the stream of water running down our path from the melting snow.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Sounds like more fun than amuserticulitis.

Comment: We are not diverted.